# Use existing custom keyboard code xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I have only custom keyboard code not full project code. I don't know how to integrate in my app or in new app. In custom keyboard some code is used that is not reachable for custom keyboards. Can any tell me how can i use this code. I know that i can make a new project with custom keyboard templCete but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

In your current app add new keyboard extension as follows
go to file/New/target/Application Extension/Custom keyboard
give some name for keyboard.

Then in your app file list "KeyboardViewController" class added.
open that KeyboardViewController.m file and just replace that keyboard code which you have.

Before running app in simulator or device first go to device 
Setting->General->keyboard->keyboards->add new keyboard 
add your custom keyboard there 
and run the app.